# Xaml grid disappears

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I have a weird problem! I want a square grid (needs to be square since a camera feed will be appearing here) while the rest can be scalable. However the green square shows up in my designer, when running it it is gone. I have tested the visibility but it also isn't clickable. Does anyone know what goes wrong here?

```
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="3*" x:Name="bottomRow"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=bottomRow, Mode=OneWay}" Name="CameraGrid" Margin="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Green">

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=bottomRow, Mode=OneWay}"` from your code and your grid pops up perfectly in the UI when code is executed.
Can you explain a little why you need to bind the width. If there is no need then remove the width binding. Grid will anyways try to take the space available.

Edit: To have uniform height and width: `Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}"`

Comment: I need the grid to be square at all times, but the resolution of the pc's might change so the image must be able to get bigger and smaller. Since the width is variable, I want to set the height the same as the width.

Comment: @Derlux I updated answer to have width same as height of the grid control itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer grid has no width or height, you see it in design time because the design time width and height values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you violating the outer grid constrains: your target row is 3* height and 1* width, then you instruct your inner grid that it should change its dimensions regardless what previous XAML says.

Let solve it another way. If you need fixed-size (or ratio) cell, let define it in outer grid row/column definitions. That way our inner grid will play safe and could consume exact space you allocate via the cell of outer grid.

Comment: I don't fully understand your answer.  If I assign a height instead of * to all the definitions it ain't working either, and putting all definitions in 1 master grid is not an option... I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: @Derlux, as others already mentioned above, WPF can be tricky sometimes in terms of layout (so it's closer to HTML tables approach rather than classical WinForms). So that, you have to train your eye to split the window into grids/sub-grids/sub-sub-grids to achieve the layout you want to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your grid with another grid and set `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Width` properties on the outer grid. Then you can bind inner Grid's with to its height.

```
<Grid Name="CameraGrid" Margin="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
    <Grid Width="{Binding ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Background="Green">

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```